# Jquery display text in div with different index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im just confused with complex describe thing. I searched in google but i couldn't find any help, maybe because i don't know exactly what to search for. I'm a newbie so, How do i append some list (ordered listing in html) in div index which was clicked.

Example.

I have a different div tab:

```
<div id="first">text</div>
<div id="first0">text</div>
<div id="first1">text</div>
<div id="first2">text</div>
<div id="first3">text</div>
<div id="first4">text</div>
<div id="first5">text</div>
```

if user click on

```
<button id = "button" type="button">Click Me!</button>
<button id = "button0" type="button">Click Me!</button>
<button id = "button1" type="button">Click Me!</button>
<button id = "button2" type="button">Click Me!</button>
<button id = "button3" type="button">Click Me!</button>
<button id = "button4" type="button">Click Me!</button>
<button id = "button5" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Then it should append some text to div id first2 if the button id 'button2' were clicked. How can i possibly do that? I'm newbie and it's hard for me to explain better than this.

Comment: Firstly, change the `id` on the `button` - it's the same as the one on the `div` when they must be unique. To solve the problem, use http://api.jquery.com/click and http://api.jquery.com/text

Comment: So you're going to have a button for each div?

Comment: @APAD1 Yes. You are right.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks. Fixed, Please have a look now.

Comment: @acoas thanks, I added an answer for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have the same `id` on the page twice, so change the `id` on the button to a `data` attribute, then on `click`, create an object from the `data` attribute to target the element you want to append, and use `$.append()`

```js
$('button').on('click',function() {
  $('#first' + $(this).data('for')).append(' more text');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first">text</div>
<div id="first0">text</div>
<div id="first1">text</div>
<div id="first2">text</div>
<div id="first3">text</div>
<div id="first4">text</div>
<div id="first5">text</div>
<button id = "button" type="button" data-for="">Click Me!</button>
<button id = "button0" type="button" data-for="0">Click Me!</button>
<button id = "button1" type="button" data-for="1">Click Me!</button>
<button id = "button2" type="button" data-for="2">Click Me!</button>
<button id = "button3" type="button" data-for="3">Click Me!</button>
<button id = "button4" type="button" data-for="4">Click Me!</button>
<button id = "button5" type="button" data-for="5">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote? If I missed the mark, I'd like to know what's off so I can offer a better solution.

Comment: I think you got me wrong. I'm having 20 div with different id and same with button, first1 will be id for div tab and for button as well. Like that for 20 or more Categories.

Comment: @acoas please update your post with your actual use case then. And keep in mind you can't have the same `id` on the page twice - you can only use an `id` once.

Comment: @acoas if I understand your comment, you would just use `<div id="first1"></div><button data-for="#first1"></button><div id="first2"></div><button data-for="#first2"></button>`, etc. But it's hard to tell what you're actually trying to do if I have to guess at your markup.

Comment: Updated. please have a look now.

Comment: I'm trying to display 10 Categories and if user click on specific Category, it should display sub Categories under the div tab placed for each Categories.

Comment: Exactly. That is it what i asked for. Thank you.

Comment: @acoas you're welcome. updated my answer to reflect your new code.

Answer (score 1):

IDs need to be unique. Instead of giving the button an ID that's the same as the DIV, use a `data` attribute to hold the related DIV. You can then turn this into a selector to use to update that DIV.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("#" + $(this).data("rel")).append(" More text");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first">text</div>
<div id="first0">text</div>
<div id="first1">text</div>
<div id="first2">text</div>
<div id="first3">text</div>
<div id="first4">text</div>
<div id="first5">text</div>

<button data-rel="first4">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by equating the `id` attributes of each button to the relevant div, however that is very brittle, not DRY and as a result will become a pain to maintain.

A better alternative is to get rid of the `id` attributes completely and relate each `button` to a `div` by their indexes within relative containers, something like this:

```js
$('.button-container button').click(function() {
  $('.content-container div').eq($(this).index()).toggle();
})
```

```css
.content-container div { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button-container">
  <button type="button">Toggle 0</button>
  <button type="button">Toggle 1</button>
  <button type="button">Toggle 2</button>
  <button type="button">Toggle 3</button>
  <button type="button">Toggle 4</button>
  <button type="button">Toggle 5</button>
</div>
<div class="content-container">
  <div>0</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

This pattern has the added benefit that to add more content is a simple matter of adding another button/div combination in the HTML; you don't have to amend the JS at all.

Comment: Thanks or your effort. Appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Since all the previous answers are relevant, I tried to make something custom that works with or without **id**s

```js
$(function(){ // jQuery DOM ready      
    var container = $("#container");
    container.on("click", "button", appendText);
    function appendText(e) {
      var id = $('input')[0].value
      var text = $('textarea')[0].value
      container.find('div')[id].append(text)     
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="container">
<textarea></textarea><br />
<input type="number" min="0" max="6" value="4" />
<button>Click me</button>
  <div>text0</div>
  <div>text1</div>
  <div>text2</div>
  <div>text3</div>
  <div>text4</div>
  <div>text5</div>
  <div>text6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks or your effort. Appreciated!